# Calling empty default constructor of type

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I'm trying to instantiate every property (of type JobVmInput) on my object.
This is my code so far:

```
var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();

foreach (var p in properties)
{
     var type = p.PropertyType;
     if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(JobVmInput)))
     {
          var constructor = type.cons.GetConstructor(**what to input here**);
          p.SetValue(p, constructor.Invoke(**what to input here**));
     }
}
```

However I don't know what to input in the GetConstructor and constructor.Invoke methods. I've looked at the MSDN documentation but I'm quite uncertain in regards to what they accept. I just want to call the empty default constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
var constructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
p.SetValue(this, constructor.Invoke());
```

Or:

```
p.SetValue(this, Activator.CreateInstance(type));
```

Note that I have replaced first parameter to `this` since the `SetValue` method expects an instance of your `object` not the `PropertyInfo`